# Spark rdd is empty until I do .count()

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a method that converts ArrayBuffer of Strings into RDD.

```
def makeRddFromArray() : RDD[String] = {
val rdd = Conf.sc.parallelize(listOfStrings)
//rdd.count
rdd}
```

With commented rdd.count() it's returning a rdd of size 0. When I uncomment this, the RDD is of proper size. Could someone explain me why? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

rdd.count is an Action which will trigger the DAG and get the count of elements.

rdd will only specify the class

```
scala> rdd
res0: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize 
at <console>:24
```

Its not performing anything here.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
Later in the code I have :
`val finalRDD = sc.union(listOfStringRDD)`

If I have commented this `.count()` method in `makeRDDFromArray` method 
`println("Final RDD size: " + rdd.count())` prints 0.
With commented it prints 100 what is right.